# Instagram API: I get no access_token

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I am using [this PHP Instagram Client](https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API) to try to access the API of Instagram, but every time I try to access it, I get this message in return:

```
object(stdClass)#4 (1) {
  ["meta"]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
    ["code"]=>
    int(400)
    ["error_type"]=>
    string(25) "OAuthAccessTokenException"
    ["error_message"]=>
    string(37) "The access_token provided is invalid."
  }
}
```

and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

This is my code so far:

```
$instagram = new MetzWeb\Instagram\Instagram('......');
$result = $instagram->getPopularMedia();
var_dump($result);
```

When I check my `$instagram` object, the data inside does not seem right, as there seems to be no access token.

```
object(MetzWeb\Instagram\Instagram)#3 (7) {
  ["_apikey":"MetzWeb\Instagram\Instagram":private]=>
  string(32) "...."
  ["_apisecret":"MetzWeb\Instagram\Instagram":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_callbackurl":"MetzWeb\Instagram\Instagram":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_accesstoken":"MetzWeb\Instagram\Instagram":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_signedheader":"MetzWeb\Instagram\Instagram":private]=>
  bool(false)
```

What is it that I am missing?

Comment: You have to implement the `getLoginUrl` / `getOAuthToken` flow laid out in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see on the github repo:

> **Note:** On the 17 Nov 2015 Instagram made changes to their API . Apps
>   created before Nov 17, 2015 wont be affected until Jun 2016. Apps
>   created on or after Nov 17 2015 will require to use their updated API.
>   Please note that this library doesn't yet support their new updates.
>   For more information, please see #182.

Meaning the library does not yet support the latest Instagram API.

**UPDATE:**
Instagram only allows authenticated API calls, no public calls anymore.

The only way to bypass public calls is by 'scraping' data from Instagram. There are a couple of scrapers out there.

- A nicer scraper is: https://github.com/vinkla/instagram

It basically fetches: https://www.instagram.com/jerryseinfeld/media/ and parses the JSON. You can fetch all tags by getting the #tags from the message.

Comment: Touche! The warning was so clearly in front of the title, that I cannot believe I missed it -_- Thanks for the suggestions and alternatives.

Comment: Interesting, though! The first alternative library you gave me produces me the exact same problems! The second one doesnt, but sadly does not have the ability to search by hashtag, which is what I look for..

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent, Hmmm, that's odd. You could try using a forked repository from your original library: https://github.com/propeopleua/Instagram-PHP-API which should include the fixes.

Comment: "propeopleua" is not my original library. it is the one you recommended.

Comment: Yes, but it's a fork from https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API, which you were using.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145985/discussion-between-enrique-moreno-tent-and-reinierkors).